Use Azure Pipelines with Azure Devops PAT authentication
I am trying to run an Azure pipeline using the Azure CLI. I can manage to do this if I log into Azure CLI using az login. However this doesn't seem to support PAT authentication. Logging in with echo PAT | az devops login doesn't allow me to use
az pipelines run --id xx --project "yyyy" --organization "zzzz" as it returns a 404 each time I try.
Is there a way to run the pipelines with PAT authentication? I need this to trigger a website build pipeline from the cms itself. az login doesn't seem like a good way to do this because it needs someone to log into the vm periodically.
This works:
az login

az pipelines --id xx --project "yyy"

This does not work and gives a 404 each time:
echo PAT | az devops login --organization="zzzz"`

az pipelines --id xx --project "yyyy"



Logging in with echo PAT | az devops login doesn't allow me to use az pipelines run --id xx --project "yyyy" --organization "zzzz" as it returns a 404 each time I try.

HTTP status code 404 means "Not found", so your problem is probably caused by using wrong parameters in az pipelines run command.
When using a pipeline, you can use predefined variables to sign in with a personal access token (PAT) and queue a build in your organization/project.
Piping PAT on StdIn to az devops login:
- script: >-
    echo "$(System.AccessToken)" | az devops login --organization $(System.CollectionUri)

    az pipelines run
    --id '123456'
    --org $(System.CollectionUri)
    --project $(System.TeamProject)
    # ...other parameters here
  displayName: 'Queue pipeline'

Using the AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT environment variable (recommended):
- script: >-
    az pipelines run
    --id '123456'
    --org $(System.CollectionUri)
    --project $(System.TeamProject)
    # ...other parameters here
  displayName: 'Queue pipeline'
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)


I'm trying to run a pipeline from a vm which contains the cms. The pipeline already exists and works fine with git hooks. My problem here is authenticating the az cli to invoke az pipelines run command. For some reason authenticating using az devops cli does not allow me to access the pipelines. But if I login using az login which makes me sign in using the browser (in the case of the vm through  a device token) works fine. Used the same configurations in both cases.

@Meowzer you mean queue a new pipeline using a build agent running on a VM?
Double-check if the PAT is valid and has the right permissions for what you're trying to do. Try running the script first in your local machine using echo  "my-token" | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/ or as alternative setting the environment variable I suggested. Please note that when you use the environment variable you should NOT run az devops login command.

Details about signing in using an Azure DevOps personal access token (PAT) can be found in the links I provided in my answer.
